# Store and processing about 30000 values read in 30 seconds

Tags: esp32, array

I am reading an accelerometer using an esp32.

- interval = 30000; (30 sec)
- offsetx, offsety and offsetz are values calculated on another function which I am using to calibrate it.

If I do like this I get about 28000 readings ( value of i-1)

```
void reading_mpu(){
  Serial.println("Start reading mpu:");
  unsigned long StartTime = millis();

  int i = 0;

  while(1){
    unsigned long CurrentTime = millis();
 
    if (CurrentTime - StartTime < interval) {  //interval is 30000
      mpu.update();

      float total_acc = sqrt((pow((mpu.getAccX() - offsetx), 2) + pow((mpu.getAccY() - offsety), 2) + pow((mpu.getAccZ() - offsetz), 2) ));
      i++;
    }  
    else if (CurrentTime - StartTime > interval) {
      Serial.println("Time end");
      Serial.println(i-1);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

If I add before "i++"

```
Serial.println(total_acc);
```

I get around 4800 values so much less values , probably because of the time that serial print is take.

If I add before "i++"

```
file_acc.println(total_acc);
```

(try to store values in a txt file on spiffs) I get around 16700 values. Much more than on serial print but still less that what is in first try.

My project consists in calculate average and max of this array of values.

I also tried define an array to store them but esp32 is crashing (probably memory :) )

Any idea of how can I get those values (hopefully a number of values as close of 28000) stored and be able to calculate average and max ?

Thank you very much

Comment: calculating and printing are very different things.  accelerometers also need filtering (in your case max and average).  It's often pointless to store all the values.  for the max, just store the max so far. 
for average consider only keeping something akin to a total or better yet- a low pass filtered value.  Then only print something for a very large number of values

Comment: You are partially right, but maybe I was not clear enough, except calculate average and max which can be done without storing them, I need to store them as well...

Comment: to store: allocate sufficient memory before even beginning the sampling.  do you need to store x,y,z, and magnitude or just that float total_acc magnitude?

Comment: What kind of processing, other than average and max, do you need to do with those values? Are you absolutely sure you need to store all the data? If you really have to store all that, and have not enough RAM, the only solution will be to find an MCU with more RAM.

Comment: You don't need to store values to know average and max. All you need is the total of all values, which you divide by the number of values, for the average, and the current max which you update if a sample exceeds it.

Comment: As `sqrt()` and `pow()` need some time, too, you might want to calculate the square by multiplication (probably faster than `pow(..., 2)`), and perhaps you don't need the `sqrt()` depending on the evaluation. However, check what you gain from this before using it in production code.